# Limits with logarithms

Tags: limits

Let $r_1, r_2, \ldots r_n \geq 0$ be real numbers. Consider the function
$$
g(x) = -x\ln \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{-r_i/x}\right).
$$
I would like to show that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x) = \min\{r_i: i=1,\ldots, n\}$.

What I did was to come up with an easy bound for all values of $g(x)$. Let $d=\min\{r_i\}$ and $u=\max\{r_i\}$. Then, it is easy to show that $d\leq g(x)\leq u$, for all $x$. But, how can I show that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x)\leq d$?

In fact, by plotting a graph, we can see that $\lim_{x\to 0^-}g(x)=u$. Feel free to let me know any hints or how can I approach this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's set $d = \min r_i$, if we factorize, we get

$\begin{align*}
g(x)& = -x \ln \left( e^{-d/x} \cdot \frac{1}{n} \sum e^{-(r_i-r)/x}\right) = -x\ln(e^{-d/x}) -x \ln \left(\frac{k}{n} + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{r_i \neq d} e^{-(r_i-d)/x} \right)\\
&= d - x \ln \left(\frac{k}{n} + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{r_i \neq d} e^{-(r_i-d)/x} \right)
\end{align*}$
where $k = |\{i \mid r_i = d\}|$

When $x \to 0^+$, for $r_i >d$ we get $e^{-(r_i-d)/x} \to 0$ so $\ln \left(\frac{k}{n} + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{r_i \neq d} e^{-(r_i-d)/x} \right) \to \ln \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$, which means $x \ln \left(\frac{k}{n} + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{r_i \neq d} e^{-(r_i-d)/x} \right) \to 0$.

This gives you $g(x) \to d$ when $x \to 0^+$.

You can do the same with $u = \max r_i$ on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $a_i = e^{-r_i}$ and $p=\frac{1}{x}.$
Let $a = (a_1\; a_2\; \ldots \;a_n)^T.$
Now you are looking for the result of
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+} g(x) = \lim_{p\to\infty} -\ln 
\left(
\left(
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^p
\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}
\right) \\
= \lim_{p\to\infty} -\ln 
\left(
\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^p
\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}
\right) \\
= -\ln \left(\lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}
\cdot  \lim_{p\to\infty} \|a\|_p\right)
 = -\ln \left( 1\cdot \|a\|_{\infty}\right)
 = -\ln \|a\|_{\infty}
$$
The maximum of $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ corresponds with the minimum of $\{r_1,\ldots,r_n\}.$ Let $m$ be such that $a_m = \max \{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}.$ Then
$r_m = \min \{r_1,\ldots,r_n\}.$
$$
-\ln \|a\|_{\infty} = -\ln a_m = -\ln e^{-r_m} = r_m = \min \{r_1,\ldots,r_n\}
$$

Comment: nice proof, very elegant

Answer (score 0):

I believe L'Hospital will serve well here. You can rewrite $g$ as

$$g(x)=-\frac{\ln(...)}{\frac 1x}$$

however I would actually suggest that you introduce a new variable $y=-\frac{1}{x}$, in which case the entire limit becomes a little easier, since it is

$$\lim_{y\to-\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n e^{r_i y}\right)}{y}$$

and now you can use L'Hospital's rule to get that to equal

$$\lim_{y\to-\infty}\frac{\frac{\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n r_ie^{r_i y}}{\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n e^{r_i y}}}{1}=\lim_{y\to-\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n r_ie^{r_i y}}{\sum_{i=1}^n e^{r_i y}}$$

Comment: There is a final "$\lim_{y\to-\infty}$" missing + how does this answer the question?

Comment: @AnneBauval I added the limit. As for the how does it answer, it doesn't *answer* it, but it is the first two steps from which OP can try to continue if they want. The next steps are relatively straightforward, and if they are stuck, they are more than welcome to ask for further help in the comments.